# Change the parameter like this [function.value(new-value)]

Tags: javascript, function

```
function add(n) {   
    return function(x) {
        this.value = n;
        return this.value + x;
    }
}

var add3 = add(3);
var add4 = add(4);
```

I'm trying to figure out if I can re-write this function above to:
Allow to modify the first parameter like this:

```
add3.value(1);
console.log(add3(4))
// 5
```

Also so that the value method returns the current value if no parameter is passed:

```
add3.value(1);
console.log(add3.value())
// 1
```

Comment: is there a reason you want to use the "value" method? it would be simpler to just use it like: `var add3 = add(3); add3(4);`

Comment: I don't know if I wrote the function right, I'm still new. I just want to be able to modify the value by saying add3.value(5) and it will change the first value to 5.

Comment: Ah, I think I minunderstood. My answer won't probably isn't quite what you're after.

Comment: Using `this.value` is wrong. You are involuntarily  creating a global variable `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are just objects, so you can assign a property `value` to it, whose value is a function that modifies `n`:

```
function add(n) { 
    var result = function(x) {
       return n + x;
    };
    result.value = function(x) {
       if (typeof x === 'undefined') {
         return n;
       }
       n = x;
    };
    return result;
}
```

Why you'd want to do that I don't know, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

To use the interface you've described, your inner function will need to return a object with a 'value' method.
eg.

```
function add (n) {
    return {
        value: function (x) {
            x = x || 0;
            return n + x;
        }
    };
}
```

But, what it sounds like you're trying to do is currying & partial application. In which case, returning a function is probably simpler.

```
function add (n) {
    return function (x) {
        x = x || 0;
        return n + x;
    };
}
```

This would be used like so:

```
var add3 = add(3);
console.log(add3(4)); // output: 7
```

or, with the default value:

```
var add4 = add(4);
console.log(add4()); // output: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Felix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23050288/1615483), but permitting empty inputs, remembering last values and also giving it a `valueOf` so it can be used like a number itself.

```
function adder(i) {
    i || (i = 0);
    var add = function (x) {
        return i += (+x || 0); // += modifies i
    };
    add.value = function (x) {
        return !x && x !== 0 ? i : i = (+x || 0); // if x falsy but not zero
    };
    add.valueOf = function () {
        return i;
    };
    return add;
}
var add = adder();
add.value(1); //  1
add(4);       //  5
add(5);       // 10
add + 2;      // 12, via valueOf
add();        // 10
```